# Entity Framework. Optimization of the db

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework-4

How can i optimize work with db ?

I am currently using:

```
using (var dataDb = new DataDBEntities())
{
    foreach (var data in reportData.DBData.Output)
    {
        dataDb.ReportTable.Add(new ReportTable()
        {
            Node = reportData.Node,
            ChartType = chartType,
            ResultType = data.Type,
            Mean = data.Statistics.Mean,
            Mode = data.Statistics.Mode,
            .....
        });
    }
    dataDb.SaveChanges();
}
```

I need in a short time to complete table of 1000 entries. But this simple work not fast

Are there any alternatives?

Comment: You can try only saving changes every X entries ... one instance, 100 worked pretty well, but you will want to test it yourself.

Comment: What's "not fast"? You're doing it correctly - adding the new entities and then calling `.SaveChanges()` at the end is optimal. If you were saving changes inside the loop that would be slower.

Comment: If you need extremely fast inserts, check out [`SqlBulkCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx).

Comment: is there any columns in your database that contains a lot of data? Do you save any data in a stupid format XML as a nvarchar(max) f.ex?
It feels like the problem isn't in this query, this should take under a second unless you have huge piles of data.

Sure SqlBulkCopy is faster than using a O-RM like EF but if it's just 1000 entries it shouldn't make a huge diffrence in performance.

is reportData.DBData.Output a direct call to the database? What if you enumrate it?